# How to avoid error when user enters no input in a tkinter entry box?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, user-interface, tkinter

Hi I am trying to get a solution for, if a user enters no value into an entry box, it doesn't create an error.
i have tried:

```
if players_math_answer_var.get() is None or players_math_answer_var.get() == "":
    players_math_answer_var.set(0)
```

also tried to set the value to 0 when initializing tk variable

```
[![players_math_answer_var = tk.IntVar(value=0)][1]][1]
```

But still get this error message (See screen shot)

[image]

Comment: Please don't include screenshots of errors. Instead, take the time to copy, paste, and format the error.

Comment: @BryanOakley Ok, i though it might have been easier to see it as a screenshot but will do in future.

Comment: Screenshots are not searchable, we can't copy/paste them, and visually impaired people can't read them at all.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you want it to be impossible for errors to occur, so try the try - except statement

```
try : # do this 
    # .....
except : # if error happened do this 
    # .....
```